# PyQt5 Changing native dialog save text?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Is it possible to change the Save/Open/Cancel text of native file dialogs called by Qt, e.g.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
OpenFile = QFileDialog()
OpenFile.getExistingDirectory()
```

I've tried following some examples in C++, e.g. [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/74854/change-qfiledialog-buttons-text/10), but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
OpenFile = QFileDialog()

#OpenFile.getExistingDirectory()

OpenFile.setFileMode(QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly)    
OpenFile.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Accept, "+Accept+")
OpenFile.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Reject, "-REJECT-")
OpenFile.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, only `QFileDialog.Accept` works on macOS, while `QFileDialog.Reject` is ignored. In any case, changing the accept button is the most important to me.